# Submit into database after choice radio button, Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, radio-button, codeigniter-4

I want to add data from the radio button selection, but the data can't be saved properly. I really need help.

Code in view

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart('home/saveCovid') ?>
<?php 
 for ($i=1; $i <=1; $i++){
 ?>
 <input type="radio" name="anotasi1<?php echo $i ? "" :     ($anotasi->anotasi == "Positif" ? "checked" : "") ?>" value="Positif">Positif<br>
                <input type="radio" name="anotasi1<?php echo $i ? "" : ($anotasi->anotasi == "Negatif" ? "checked" : "") ?>" value="Negatif">Negatif<br>
                <input type="radio" name="anotasi1<?php echo $i ? "" : ($anotasi->anotasi == "Netral" ? "checked" : "") ?>" value="Netral">Netral<br>
<?php
 }
  ?>
 </td>
 </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        
        </div>
```

Code in controller

```html
public function saveCovid()
    {
       $data['anotasi1'] = $this->input->post('anotasi1');
    }
```

Code in Model

```html
protected $table = 'tbl_anotasi';
    
    public function alldata()
    {
        return $this->db->table('tbl_anotasi')->get()->getResultArray();
    }

    public function add($data)
    {
        $this->db->table('tbl_anotasi')->insert($data);
    }
```

Comment: Your controller is not sending any data to the model.

Answer (score 0):

The line of

```
$data['anotasi1'] = $this->input->post('anotasi1');
```

saves `anotasi1`'s value into an array called `$data`. While that may be useful, what you actually need is to save this value by calling the `add` method of your model.